# Sql Server security Issue

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql

how to add Sql server user for specific database with backup and restore permission only ??

Answer (score 4):

> BACKUP DATABASE and BACKUP LOG
>   permissions default to members of the
>   sysadmin  fixed server role and the
>   db_owner and **db_backupoperator**  fixed
>   database roles.

So your user must be added to the fixed role [db_backupoperator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189041.aspx).

You do not want to have an user that has 'restore permission only'. Restores are performed by the database owner only (ie. sysadmin, db_owner or db_creator members). There is no such dedicated role as 'db_restoreoperator' and there cannot be one, because an user that can restore arbitrary content into a database is in effect the owner of the database: it can use backup/restore as a vector to alter the content of the database as he/she likes, so such a role would be a masquerade of security.

Comment: you mean that i need to make a user as database owner